# Twython - Do I Need a Callback_URL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

I'd like to be able to post tweets from a Python script, that runs from a server cron. I've been following the Twython documentation (https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#obtain-authorization-url) but i'm not sure if I require a callback_url.

> Only pass callback_url to get_authentication_tokens if your application is a Web Application
>
> Desktop and Mobile Applications do not require a callback_url

Does anyone know if I require one? I tried putting in "google.com" but returned a 401 error.

Here's my code currently:

```
app_name = "AppNameTestScript"

APP_KEY = "exAmPlE"
APP_SECRET = "exAmPlEexAmPlEexAmPlE"

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens(callback_url='http://google.com.au')
```

Comment: Can we see a little bit more of your code?

Comment: @WilliamDenman, updated question with code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use application-level authorisaion, you should use [Oath2 authorisation path](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#oauth-2-application-authentication)

Oath1 authorisation is a bit trickier, your application is authorised to act on behalf of an end user, so the latter has to grant this authority to your application. End user opens `auth['auth_url']` url and grants permissions to your app on twitter.com, then he is redirected back to the application, that is where callback is used for. By processing this redirect, a web-based application communicates for access token. Read [oauth begguide](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/workflow/) for more details.

There is a [pin-based](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization) authoriazation flow in case you can't implement redirect handling. For this, you don't need to provide `callback_url`, as user acceptance is handled differently. Your end user however still need somehow communicate to your application his pin code. See twython docs for steps starting from when you know pin [implementation details](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#handling-the-callback)